# Como usar ng-change para controlar un toggle

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap

Resulta tengo un switch de la librería de **Angular Bootstrap Toggle** y necesito controlar su función mediante `ng-change`.

En mi html tengo el switch de la siguiente manera:

```
<toggle ng-model="ValueResponse" ng-change="changed()" on="Enabled" off="Disabled"></toggle> :Movil.
```

`ValueResponse` corresponde a la función que me indica el estado del móvil, es decir, si se encuentra activo o inactivo

```
Conection.CheckMovil({
    sucursal_id: SaveCredentials.getData().id_sucursal
  }, function(respuesta) {

      var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(respuesta));
      var activo = data.activo;

      if(activo == "1"){
          $scope.ValueResponse = true
      } else {
          $scope.ValueResponse = false
      }
});
```

Ahora me falta controlar la función `change()`

La petición para activar:

```
$scope.changed = Conection.OnMovil({
    sucursal_id: SaveCredentials.getData().id_sucursal
}, function(response){

});
```

La petición para desactivar:

```
$scope.changed2 = Conection.OffMovil({ 
    sucursal_id: SaveCredentials.getData().id_sucursal
}, function(response){

});
```

Entonces con `ng-change` puedo poner solo una y al activar y desactivar siempre se ejecutara la misma... como lo soluciono? o como puedo implementar el código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas usar `ng-change` para controlar esto. Esta directiva está diseñada para trabajar en elementos `input` y tu estas usando una directiva llamada `toggle`.

De todas maneras es muy fácil escribir

```
$scope.$watch('ValueResponse', function(val) {
    if (!angular.isUndefined(val)) {
        if (val) {
            Conection.OnMovil({
                sucursal_id: SaveCredentials.getData().id_sucursal
            }, function(response){
                // callback
            });
        } else {
            Conection.OffMovil({ 
                sucursal_id: SaveCredentials.getData().id_sucursal
            }, function(response){
                // callback
            });
        }
    }
});
```

ya que dicha directiva está haciendo binding con el valor de `'ValueResponse'` en tu modelo.

Ten en cuenta que si el usuario activa/desactiva muy rápido estarás haciendo muchas llamadas ajax consecutivas por lo que te recomiendo que hagas un [throttle](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

Comment: Elimino me propuesta y me sumo a la tuya +1. Tampoco habia utilizado mucho `$scope.watch`, ahora lei la documentación y me quedo claro!

Comment: Master! Gracias. amigo.